# Editable and Formatted Text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm working on a note taking app and looking for a way to store, format and edit text from a UITextView. Currently I'm only able to store normal strings in CoreData. What would be the best way to make that text formattable and store it afterwards in CoreData?

Comment: Have you looked at the `allowsEditingTextAttributes` of `UITextView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would be the best way to make that text formattable and store it afterwards in CoreData?

The text view's `attributedText` is an NSAttributedString. Archive that to Data / NSData and store that. You can make that simpler by using a value transformer.

Comment: But how can I add an attribute for a selected bit of the text? For example make that text bold.

Comment: That is not what you asked. If you don't know how to use NSAttributedString, do a search. It has been explained here very often.

Answer (score 0):

Represent the formatting as HTML text. The AttributedString can parse HTML.
You might have to write your own algorithm to represent your output formatting as HTML text. After that you just store the string the regular way (Simple string in CoreData).

Here is a good tutorial on HTML and AttributedString:
https://medium.com/theappspace/swift-how-to-convert-html-using-nsattributedstring-8c6ffeb7046f